# ABP.IO - Handle multiple events in same microservice

Tags: c#, microservices, abp, event-driven

Considering the below documentation and the example to handle different events

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Distributed-Event-Bus#pre-defined-events

Do I need to have 3 microservices to handle create, update & Delete for a resource?

or Do I need to write something like this?

```
namespace AbpDemo
{
    public class MyHandler
        : IDistributedEventHandler<EmployeeServiceEto>,
          ITransientDependency
    {
        public async Task HandleEventAsync(EmployeeServiceEto eventData)
        {
            if(eventData.EventType = EventType.Created;
                // call Create Employee Method
            if(eventData.EventType = EventType.Updated;
                // call Update Employee Method
            if(eventData.EventType = EventType.GetAll;
                // call GetAllEmployees
            
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with an example of handling multiple events in the same microservice using [apb.io](https://abp.io/) framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABP Framework provides three pre-defined event types such as `EntityCreatedEto<T>`, `EntityUpdatedEto<T>`, and `EntityDeletedEto<T>`. You can use these types to subscribe for create, update, and delete events.

You can see the following example:

```cs
namespace AbpDemo
{
    public class MyHandler : 
          IDistributedEventHandler<EntityCreatedEto<EmployeeServiceEto>>,
          IDistributedEventHandler<EntityUpdatedEto<EmployeeServiceEto>>,
          IDistributedEventHandler<EntityDeletedEto<EmployeeServiceEto>>,
          ITransientDependency
    {
       public virtual async Task HandleEventAsync(EntityCreatedEto<EmployeeServiceEto> eventData)
       {
          //your logic for when a new entity created
       }

       public virtual async Task HandleEventAsync(EntityUpdatedEto<EmployeeServiceEto> eventData)
       {
          //your logic for when the entity updated
       }

       public virtual async Task HandleEventAsync(EntityDeletedEto<EmployeeServiceEto> eventData)
       {
          //your logic for when the entity deleted
       }
    }
}
```

If you do it like that, then you don't need to check the `EventType`. An example from the ABP Framework can be seen [here](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/test/DistEvents/DistDemoApp.Shared/TodoEventHandler.cs#L11-L13).

Comment: Great, thanks!   How do we do it for events like GetAll or Get or any other custom event?

Comment: https://github.com/abpframework/eventhub/blob/31a28f1b16676653e25af72a7cb89b0e0308e259/src/EventHub.Domain/Organizations/PaymentRequests/PaymentRequestEventHandler.cs something like this will help to handle custom events? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is how you can handle custom events. Define an eto class, publish it, and subscribe to it using the `IDistributedEventHandler<TEtoClass>`, this is the flow.